# Groovy property definition

Tags: groovy

Previously I'd thought that a property in Groovy is indicated by the omission of a scoping keyword. In other words

```
class Test {
   def prop = "i am a property"
   public notProp = "i am not"
}
```

However, it appears I'm incorrect about this, because the following script prints "getter val"

```
class Foo {
  public bar = "init val"

  public getBar() {
    "getter val"
  }
}

println new Foo().bar
```

The fact that the getter is invoked when `bar` is accessed suggests that `bar` is a property rather than a field. So what exactly is the difference between fields and properties in Groovy.

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 3):

In order to access a field directly you have to prepend it with an @ sign:

```
assert "getter val" == new Foo().bar
assert "init val" == new Foo().@bar
```

That the short form of `new Foo().getBar()` works, although `bar` is not a property, is  still concise from my point of view.

In contrast you can't make a call to `foo.setBar("setter val")`, but you could in case you would have defined `bar` as a property without the access modifier.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a difference that isn't there in groovy.

["In Groovy, fields and properties have been merged so that they act and look the same."](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Beans)

Comment: They may look the same and act the same mostly, but Groovy will only generate a getter/setter for a property, which is defined by the presence of an access modifier.

Answer (score 1):

Using a modifier does indeed suppress the creation of a property. What is confusing you is that `.` seems to fallback on a field access when no such a property exists.

```
$ groovysh
Groovy Shell (2.1.0, JVM: 1.7.0_21)
Type 'help' or '\h' for help.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
groovy:000> class A { def a = "foo" };
===> true
groovy:000> new A().getA()
===> foo
groovy:000> new A().a
===> foo
groovy:000> new A().properties
===> {class=class A, a=foo}
```

But:

```
groovy:000> class A { public def a = "foo" };
===> true
groovy:000> new A().getA()
ERROR groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:
No signature of method: A.getA() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: getAt(java.lang.String), grep(), grep(java.lang.Object), with(groovy.lang.Closure), putAt(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object), wait()
        at groovysh_evaluate.run (groovysh_evaluate:2)
        ...
groovy:000> new A().a
===> foo
groovy:000> new A().properties
===> {class=class A}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think @Christoph Metzendorf answer was correct...

> In order to access a field directly you have to prepend it with an @
>   sign:
>
> ```
> assert "getter val" == new Foo().bar
> assert "init val" == new Foo().@bar
> ```

... but I would add that in your `Foo` example your `getBar` method overrode the `getBar` method that Groovy generated for you.  You can use the above syntax to access `bar` directly if you want to continue overriding the default `getBar` method Groovy generated for you, or you could just not override `getBar` so any call to `getBar` will use the getter Groovy generated for you.